# HttpClientFactory - Get a named, typed client by its name

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

HttpClientFactory offers the following extension method:

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClient<TClient>(this IServiceCollection services, string name)
```

and I've created a typed HttpClient as follows:

```
public class CustomClient {

    public CustomClient(HttpClient client,
        CustomAuthorizationInfoObject customAuthorizationInfoObject) {
        /// use custom authorization info to customize http client
    }

    public async Task<CustomModel> DoSomeStuffWithClient() {
        /// do the stuff
    }

}
```

I can register this custom client in the program's ServiceCollection as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizationInfoObject>();
services.AddHttpClient<CustomClient>("DefaultClient");
```

I can then register a second instance of this CustomClient with some slightly altered info in it:

```
services.AddHttpClient<CustomClient>("AlternativeAuthInfo", (client) => {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = ...;
});
```

Elsewhere in the program I now want to get a specific named `CustomClient`. This is proving the obstacle.

I can get whichever `CustomClient` was added to services last simply by requesting `CustomClient` from the service provider.

Calling `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient("AlternativeAuthInfo")`, for example, returns an `HttpClient`, so I can't access the extra method in CustomClient, and there don't appear to be any other methods there that help me.

How therefore do I go about getting a named CustomClient? Or am I misusing the opportunity to name and reference a typed client via the original extension method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see that there is a `ITypedHttpClientFactory<>` interface that can wrap a regular `HttpClient` in a typed one. Not used it personally, but is that the missing piece?

e.g.

```
/// grab the named httpclient
var altHttpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("AlternativeAuthInfo");

/// get the typed client factory from the service provider
var typedClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<CustomClient>>();

/// create the typed client
var altCustomClient = typedClientFactory.CreateClient(altHttpClient);
```

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.itypedhttpclientfactory-1.createclient?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I had seen that but it doesn't appear to care for a name that an HttpClient has. Although I suppose I could grab the named HttpClient myself and then use that it return the typed one. I'll have a little play

Comment: Looks to be the missing piece, thanks! It feels a bit clunky - to me I wonder why IHttpClientFactory couldn't have a generic CreateClient<TypedClient>("name") method to bypass this - but nonetheless will do the job