# DI named custom HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I have a custom http client `CustomHttpClient`

I have to use `IHttpClientFactory` as azure auth, which I am trying to get to work, needs `.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>()`

How can I ensure that the named client I am adding with `AddHttpClient` is `CustomHttpClient` not just `HttpClient`

I tried

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<CustomHttpClient>("xxx", client =>
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomHttpClient>(sp => (CustomHttpClient)sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("xxx"));
```

but the .NET doesn't like the cast in the `AddScoped`

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding on how to use `IHttpClientFactory`.

`IHttpClientFactory` always create `HttpClient` and never create `TClient` which is specified as the type argument of `AddHttpClient` method.

The `TClient` class is where you can inject the configured client. The [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#typed-clients) says,

> A typed client accepts an HttpClient parameter in its constructor

So, configuring services like:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<CustomHttpClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://custom.api.com");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AnotherHttpClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://another.api.com");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

then, we can implement the `CustomHttpClient` class like:

```cs
public class CustomHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public CustomHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client; //<-- This client has base URL "http://custom.api.com"
    }

    public Task<string> GetSomething(string apiPath)
    {
        return _client.GetStringAsync(apiPath);
    }
}
```

If you still want to create HttpClient by name, you can give a name when calling `AddHttpClient` method as you did, and inject `ITypedHttpClientFactory<CustomHttpClient>` to CustomHttpClient and create HttpClient from it with name. But in such case, I don't see the reason to use `ITypedHttpClientFactory`. maybe, `IHttpClientFactory` is the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `CustomHttpClient` class derives from `HttpClient` you cannot use `IHttpClientFactory` directly. However you can build your own factory and produce similar behavior by using `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory`

```
public class CustomHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    public CustomHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler)
        : base(handler, disposeHandler)
    {
    }

    // ... your code 
}

public class CustomHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpMessageHandlerFactory _handlerFactory;

    public CustomHttpClientFactory(IHttpMessageHandlerFactory handlerFactory)
    {
        _handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    public CustomHttpClient CreateClient(string name)
    {
        var handler = _handlerFactory.CreateHandler(name);
        return new CustomHttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I was wrong where I assumed your `CustomHttpClient` does not derive from ´HttpClient` like described in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory)

`CustomHttpClient` does not inherit from the `HttpClient` class. So the cast would always fail.

If you do not need to have multiple different named instances of `CustomHttpClient` all you need is `AddHttpClient<Type>()` and you can consume `CustomHttpClient` directly via DI.

In case you need multiple typed, named instances you can use the `ITypedHttpClientFactory` approach described in the answer of [HttpClientFactory - Get a named, typed client by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201914/httpclientfactory-get-a-named-typed-client-by-its-name) and build your own Factory class like this

```
public class CustomHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly ITypedHttpClientFactory<CustomHttpClient> _typedClientFactory;

    public CustomHttpClientFactory(
        IHttpClientFactory httpClient,
        ITypedHttpClientFactory<CustomHttpClient> typedClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClient;
        _typedClientFactory = typedClientFactory;
    }

    public CustomHttpClient CreateClient(string name)
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(name);
        return _typedClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: `CustomHttpClient ` does actually inherit from `HttpClient`. Does that change anything in your suggestion?

Comment: Interesting... That usually that's now what you do when using typed clients: According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory) a typed client is a class that accepts a `HttpClient` instance.
I do not think the inherited version will work with `IHttpClientFactory` as described in my answer

Comment: Turns out you can use `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` to create handlers and mimic the behavior of `IHttpClientFactory` however I would still prefer to stick with the standard way.